Implement Spring Security with multiple overlapping AuthenticationProvider
I'm trying to configure my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to be able to authenticate two different (and incompatible) authentication flows. To make it simple, the requests sent to the server can have two possible type of token in the header, each type has its own header key (ex: 'webAuth' and 'hardwareAuth').
Rigth now, I have an AuthenticationProvider and ProcessingFilter for each flow.
I set up my configuration as follow:
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(unauthorizedEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(webAuthenticationProvider)
                .authenticationProvider(hardwareAuthenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(webAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(hardwareAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(ANT_MATCHES).not().authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable();
    }

webAuthenticationProvideris executed before hardwareAuthenticationProvider.
The problems are the following:

Even if the first provider correctly authenticate, the second one is executed and as - expected fails. As result, the request return 401.
If the first provider doesn't authenticate the request, the second one is not executed, and as result the request return 401.

I'd like to introduce a mechanism that allow me to either perform correctly both authentication or to only execute the 'correct' one programmatically checking the header beforhand.
Here the implementation of my providers:
@Component
public class HardwareAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private HardwareTokenService hardwareTokenService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String vToken = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        if (hardwareTokenService.auth(vToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetails = new User("hw", "", new ArrayList<>());
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, vToken, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid v-token");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    @NonNull
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object token = authentication.getCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object token = authentication.getCredentials();
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(token)
                .map(t -> authenticationService.loadUserByToken(String.valueOf(t)))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("Invalid authentication token=" + token));
    }
}


Make different authentication objects so that each AuthenticationProvider operates on its dedicated Authentication object. I suspect you decided to reuse an existing Authentication implementation for both. The main problem is thus your filter which should create the dedicated Authentication object based on the header.

I'm not sure if I understand your comment, I edited the question with the Providers implementation.

As stated you are reusing an existing Authentication, the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken don't do that. Even worse you are probably using this in both your AuthenticationProvider instances. Instead create your own Authentication objects one for each custom AuthenticationProvider. That way they will only operate on the one that is actually being used (hardware or web).

As stated create your own custom Authentication object, or at least for the hardware one.
public class HardwareAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private final Object principal;
    private Object credentials;  

  public HardwareAuthenticationToken(String token) {
    super(null);
    this.credentials = token;
  }

  public HardwareAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);
    this.principal = principal;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    super.setAuthenticated(true);
  }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return this.credentials;
    }

    public String getToken() {
      return (String) this.credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return this.principal;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Assert.isTrue(!isAuthenticated,
                "Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead");
        super.setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        super.eraseCredentials();
        this.credentials = null;
    }

}

Now modify the HardwareAuthenticationProvider to use this specific token.
@Component
public class HardwareAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private HardwareTokenService hardwareTokenService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String vToken = authentication.getToken();
        if (hardwareTokenService.auth(vToken)) {
            UserDetails userDetails = new User("hw", "", new ArrayList<>());
            return new HardwareAuthenticationToken(userDetails, vToken, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid v-token");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return HardwareAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

In your HardwareAuthenticationFilter construct the HardwareAuthenticationToken using the single arg constructor instead of creating a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
You could do the same for the web based authentication and create a dedicated subclass of the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken like WebAuthenticationToken and let the other provider react to that specifically.

Solved, thank you. Didn't realized that I could use custom objects.
